# ZoomCharts -> NetChart -> How to get list of filtered nodes after chart.updateFilters() is completed

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts, netchart

I am using [NetChart](https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/examples/filters/node-filter.html) from **ZoomCharts**, It provides an option to filter nodes by providing a function in **nodeFilter** argument which is called by `chart.updateFilters()`. I want to know if there exists an event that is fired after updateFilters is completed and new chart with filtered nodes is rendered, so that I can get list of nodes that are currently rendered.

I found an event [onChartUpdate](https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/api-reference/settings/events.html#doc_onChartUpdate) but it doesn't work everytime `chart.updateFilters()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling chart.updateFilters() this triggers data update, where the nodes are validated against the filters in the next immediate rendering cycle. So, for now you can simply use setTimeout() and use api call nodes() to get the visible nodes. Alternatively, you can hook into nodeFilter() method to sync the data model state externally to keep the state always updated.

You can also request a new feature development if you need this feature in your project (write to support@zoomcharts.com)